# Windows , WinInet C++ API

Tags: c++, winapi, ftp

I am trying to use FTP to read some files from my local FTP filezilla server. However I struggle a bit, here is my code:

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<WinInet.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


HINTERNET hOpener, hCon, hFinder;
Handle hFile;
char buffer[2000] = "\0";
WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;

hOpener = InternetOpen(TEXT("Chrome"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, NULL);

hCon = InternetConnect(hOpener, TEXT("127.0.0.1"), INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, TEXT("anonymous"), TEXT("adminn"), INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, NULL);

hFinder = FtpFindFirstFile(hCon, NULL, &findData, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);

hFile = FtpOpenFile(hOpener, findData.cFileName, GENERIC_READ, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, 0);

LPDWORD x = 0;
cout << InternetReadFile(hFile, buffer, 280, x);
```

However, it prints 0 when it should print 1(basically there's a problem reading). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check each returned value, not only what `InternetReadFile` returns. If returned value indicates failure, call `GetLastError` (and `InternetGetLastResponseInfo` if necessary) to get more info about what's going wrong.

Comment: Another problem that i've seen is that if I do printf("%s ", findData.cFileName); it only shows the first character of my file, not the full name

Comment: If you have Unicode enabled for your project this is expected. `cFileName` is array of `TCHAR`s and you are printing it as if it is an array of `char`s.

Comment: yes, you are right, I had to change to multi byte

Comment: Lord, no! Changing your code to use ANSI/MBCS encoding is **not** the solution. Make it use UTF-16 throughout instead (e.g. by calling [wprintf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l), or using the `%S` format specifier in the `printf` call).

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a NULL `DWORD*` pointer to the `lpdwNumberOfBytesRead` parameter of `InternetReadFile()`.  You need to pass a pointer to a `DWORD` instead.

Change:

```
LPDWORD x = 0;
InternetReadFile(..., x);
```

to:

```
DWORD x = 0;
InternetReadFile(..., &x);
```